# Chalice Framework: Request did not specify an Accept header with image/jpeg

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, chalice

I want to return an image from a Chalice/python application. My entire application code is pasted below:

```
from chalice import Chalice, Response
import base64

app = Chalice(app_name='hello')

@app.route('/makeImage', methods=['GET'])
def makeImage():
    return Response(
        base64.b64decode(
            "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="
        ),
        headers={
            'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'
        },
        status_code=200)
```

The result...

> {"Code":"BadRequest","Message":"Request did not specify an Accept
>   header with image/jpeg, The response has a Content-Type of image/jpeg.
>   If a response has a binary Content-Type then the request must specify
>   an Accept header that matches."}

Why does this happen?

I have poured through a ton of documentation already and most of it is outdated as binary support was added to Chalice very recently:

- https://github.com/aws/chalice/pull/352
- https://github.com/aws/chalice/issues/592
- https://github.com/aws/chalice/issues/348
- [AWS Chalice Return an Image File from S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44149971/aws-chalice-return-an-image-file-from-s3) (Warning: the sole answer to this question is COMPLETELY WRONG)
- https://chalice.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html
- https://github.com/aws/chalice/issues/391 (issue WRONGLY CLOSED in 2017 without a resolution)
- https://github.com/aws/chalice/issues/1095 is a re-open of 391 above

Just for troubleshooting purposes I'm able to obtain a response by using `curl -H "accept: image/jpeg"`, but this is useless since browsers to not work this way, and I need to use the response in a browser (HTML IMG TAG).

*UPDATE*

I also tried `@app.route('/makeImage', methods=['GET'], content_types=['image/jpeg'])`

And result became `{"Code":"UnsupportedMediaType","Message":"Unsupported media type: application/json"}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue.

If no header accept is present, AWS set it to default application/json and I receive a base64 response. If I set accept to images/jpeg or any binary content type in header, then I got the images. Great but web browser to not set the accept header.

But if I add

```
app.api.binary_types =['*/*']
```

then ok my images apis now works. **Great but now the json ones fail.**

Currently I do not see any solution except having two API gateway : one for json and one for images. If you really want only one API Gateway, I think you have to use gzip conpression on all you json response to convert them to binaries.

It is more how  AWS API Gateway works with lambda proxy than a Chalice issue. But I agree, it is a big limitation

Comment: The issue w/ json breaking is also covered in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56201915/how-to-have-image-and-json-returned-from-separate-routes-in-same-chalice-applica?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug in Chalice that was fixed on 14-May-2019 and documented here:

> https://github.com/aws/chalice/issues/1095

In addition to installing the latest Chalice directly from GitHub, I also had to add:

```
app.api.binary_types =['*/*']
```

in `app.py`.

The final working code looks like this:

```
from chalice import Chalice, Response
import base64

app = Chalice(app_name='hello')
app.api.binary_types =['*/*']

@app.route('/makeImage', methods=['GET'])
def makeImage():
    return Response(
        base64.b64decode(
            "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="
        ),
        headers={
            'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'
        },
        status_code=200)
```